# Dealing with Periods in rewritten Links

Tags: url, url-rewriting, period

With the help of some amazing folks here I've successfully been able to rewrite my URLs.

My Links are now setup like this:

**mydomain.com/city/state/businessname/**

But my problem comes into play when there is a period in the link.

**http://www.mydomain.com/toronto/on/St._Christopher/**

No I have no problems with spaces (I'm replacing them with underscores, then flipping them back to spaces when looking them up in my database, but I'm not really sure how to handle the period.  I could remove it, but then when I need to look up the business name I don't know how to put the period back in to where it was.

**http://www.mydomain.com/toronto/on/St._Christopher/**

Any thoughts, or suggestions on how I can handle this better?

Thanks!!! :D